# MVC3: How to specify that a partial view be loaded when it is located in a different, non-searched, folder?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to include a partial view in a view that is located in a different folder.  So I have the following view:

```
/_mvc/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
```

It has the following line of code:

```
@Html.Partial("~/_mvc/Views/Subject/_QuickSearch.cshtml", Model.QuickSearchModel);
```

This is not working.  I keep getting the following error:

```
The partial view '~/_mvc/Views/Subject/_QuickSearch' was not found or no view 
engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/_mvc/Views/Subject/_QuickSearch
```

Am I missing something obvious?  I should point out that I have modified the routing for my application to place all MVC code in the _mvc folder.  This is not a mistake.  The application is in the process of being converted from WebForms to MVC and I wanted all the MVC stuff under one folder.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use the _mvc folder to start with, webforms wouldn't be using the Views folder to begin with?

Comment: I am using _mvc because I am converting an existing webforms application to use mvc, but I want to isolate all the mvc code so that once the webforms code has been replaced, I can easily reconfigure the app to a standard form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the root of your application is the **_mvc/** folder, then all you should need to do is:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Subject/_QuickSearch.cshtml", Model.QuickSearchModel);
```

In your case, **~** already points to **mvc_/**.